# Обрезанная рамка с фоном

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла проблема с рамкой. Раньше использовал простой `:after` и ставил тексту фон, тут же на фоне картинка, и такой вариант не прокатывает. Как это можно реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код свой представь.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header-inner-contacts">
                <div class="contacts">
                    <p class="contacts__title">
                        Работаем без выходных по Минску и обл.
                    </p>
                    <div class="contacts-phone">
                        <div class="contacts-phone__num">
                            <span class="icon-Phones"></span>
                            <a href="+375291936245">+375 29 193 62 45</a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="contacts-phone__recall">
                            Перезвоните мне
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<style>
.header-inner-contacts {
  width: 19.607%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
.header-inner-contacts .contacts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.contacts__title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.contacts-phone {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.contacts-phone__num {
  background-color: #2b2b2c;
  padding: 0 1.4rem;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.contacts-phone__num span {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #ffc009;
}
.contacts-phone__num a {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.contacts-phone__recall {
  color: #ffc009;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc009;
}
.contacts-phone:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #545455;
  top: 2rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Не пойму вашего вопроса. Вам собрать что-то нужно? Уточните конкретнее.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev нужно сделать так, чтобы текст перекрывал рамку делая её прерывистой

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n9ypaf покажите стрелочками визуально что нужно. я не понимать.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-inner-contacts {
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
.header-inner-contacts .contacts {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.contacts__title {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.contacts-phone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.contacts-phone__num {
    background-color: #2b2b2c;
    padding: 0 1.4rem;
    /* margin-top: 0.6rem; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.2rem;
}
.contacts-phone__num span {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #ffc009;
}
.contacts-phone__num a {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* margin-left: 0.5rem; */
    line-height: 1;
}
.contacts-phone__recall {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #545455;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
.contacts-phone__recall p {
    color: #ffc009;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc009;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-inner-contacts">
                <div class="contacts">
                    <p class="contacts__title">
                        Работаем без выходных по Минску и обл.
                    </p>
                    <div class="contacts-phone">
                        <div class="contacts-phone__num">
                            <span class="icon-Phones"></span>
                            <a href="+375291936245">+375 29 193 62 45</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contacts-phone__recall"><p>
                            Перезвоните мне
                        </p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```